# what does interfacename.class returns?

Tags: java

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ("applicationContext.xml");
    //retrieve bean from the spring container
    Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach",Coach.class);
    //call methods on the bean
    System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
    System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyFortune());
    System.out.println(theCoach.getEmailAddress());
    System.out.println(theCoach.getTeam());
    //close the context
    context.close();
```

In the above code ,what does the Coach.class returns

Coach is an interface.

Comment: `Coach.class` is a `Class`--specifically a `Class<Coach>`.

Comment: what will it return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything - methods (can) return values, but expressions just have values. The value of `Coach.class` is the class object for `Coach` and has the type `Class<Coach>`.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? What a class literal (`.class`) is? Or do you have an issue with the concept that an interface has an associated `Class` object?

Answer (score 0):

The `Coach.class` returns an instance of an [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object which describes the structure of the  Coach interface.

Let's suppose we have this example:

```
public interface Coach {
    int getName();
}
```

if you will execute these lines:

```
Class<Coach> coachClass = Coach.class;
System.out.println(coachClass.getName());
for(Method m:coachClass.getMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName());
}
```

You will get the full name of your interface and the name of the declared methods.

In a nutshell `Coach.class` returns the metadata of your interface. If you want to find out more about this subject then I suggest you to read about [Java Reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html)

In your case, this line of code:

```
Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach",Coach.class);
```

returns an instance of an object which implements the Coach interface. You have to pass the metadata of the `Coach` interface, so that Spring knows what type of data are you looking for.